# How to switch text view from one thing to the next when a button is clicked - Android

Tags: android, button, android-widget, textview

Below is my main activity file. I am stuck with the bottom area (commented out). I want to make it so that when I hit button `b1`, the text changes from what it is for default. So say it says "hello" by default, I want to switch the text to something like "how are you" when you press button `b1`. I have tried many things, but I always get errors. Can someone help me?

```
package com.wdmc85.donottouch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DoNotTouchActivity extends Activity 
implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.b1:
        //WHAT DO I PUT IN HERE?? I WANT IT SO WHEN YOU HIT BUTTON B1, THE 
        //TEXT CHANGES FROM WHAT IT IS FOR DEFAULT. SO SAY IT SAYS "HELLO"
        //AS DEFAULT, HOW DO I MAKE IT SO WHEN YOU PRESS BUTTON B1 THE TEXT
        //CHANGES FROM "HELLO" TO "HOW ARE YOU?" I HAVE TRIED ALL SORTS OF
        //THINGS BUT NOTHING HAS WORKED
    break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: are you want to change the text of textview or of button itself

Comment: i want to change the the text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if want to change text   of the button itself

```
 switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.b1:
           Button b1 = (Button) v;
           b1.setText("HOW ARE YOU?");

        break;
        }
```

if want to change text  of the any other Textview

```
 switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.b1:
           TextView tv = (TextView ) this.findViewById(R.id.<tvid>);
           tv .setText("HOW ARE YOU?");

        break;
        }
```

Comment: the bottom one helped, thanks, but how do i make multiple text changes, so like we already have it so that it switches it from hello to how are you, but how would i make it so that it when you clicked the button again, it switched the text to something else? like to say... "whats your favorite color?"

Answer (score 0):

You should use below method to change text of text view.

```
 textView.setText("your text");
```

reference link is >>  [textview>>setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

can use same for button and other views.